# Split text apart in table cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to align some text left and other text right in the same table cell. I tried with \hfill and it works in my MWE.

Here is a MWE that is working :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{r|l}
    \toprule
    Élément évalué & Commentaire \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Utilisabilité de l'osselet} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats \hfill (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser \hfill (4/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Texture adaptée à la saisie \hfill (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Position des capteurs adaptée \hfill (8/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \multirow{4}{*}{Utilisabilité du cube} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats \hfill (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser \hfill (6/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Texture adaptée à la saisie \hfill (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Position des capteurs adaptée \hfill (9/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \multirow{3}{*}{Utilisabilité du bracelet} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats \hfill (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser \hfill (9/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Oubli au poignet \hfill (3/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \multirow{5}{*}{Utilisabilité du verre} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats \hfill (8/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser \hfill (8/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Texture adaptée à la saisie \hfill (8/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Position des capteurs adaptée \hfill (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Bord trop épais \hfill (5/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Potentiels problèmes} & $\bullet$ Risque de chute et de casse pour le verre \hfill (3/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Contact possible électronique/eau pour le verre \hfill (1/9)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Résumé des résultats d'utilisabilité de l'étude d'utilisabilité et d'acceptabilité avec des patients}
    \label{recap_utilisabilite}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

However, it does not work with my config file as you can see below.

[image]

Here is my config file : [config file](https://ufile.io/4vh98)

Answer (score 2):

The package `colortbl` hacks the implementation of `array` and `tabular`. I think you should put the elements like `(7/7)` in a specific column. Moreover, `booktabs` should be used without any vertical rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{rlr}
    \toprule
    Élément évalué & Commentaire \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Utilisabilité de l'osselet} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats & (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser & (4/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Texture adaptée à la saisie & (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Position des capteurs adaptée & (8/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \multirow{4}{*}{Utilisabilité du cube} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats & (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser & (6/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Texture adaptée à la saisie & (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Position des capteurs adaptée & (9/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \multirow{3}{*}{Utilisabilité du bracelet} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats & (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser & (9/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Oubli au poignet & (3/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \multirow{5}{*}{Utilisabilité du verre} & $\bullet$ Taille et poids adéquats & (8/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Facile à utiliser & (8/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Texture adaptée à la saisie & (8/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Position des capteurs adaptée & (9/9)\\
     & $\bullet$ Bord trop épais & (5/9)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Potentiels problèmes} & $\bullet$ Risque de chute et de casse pour le verre & (3/9) \\
     & $\bullet$ Contact possible électronique/eau pour le verre & (1/9)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Résumé des résultats d'utilisabilité de l'étude d'utilisabilité et d'acceptabilité avec des patients}
    \label{recap_utilisabilite}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx i'll try ! 
One question, why shouldn't I use booktabs with vertical rule ?

Comment: Many designers considerer that vertical rules are useless in tabulars and that's the point of vue of the author of `booktabs`. This is explained in the manual of the package (il y a une version française de la documentation disponible sur CTAN).

Comment: Okay thanks, I just find that the table with vertical ligne is sexier :)

Comment: Some users are surprised that the rules drawn with `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` of `booktabs` are not joined with the vertical rules. It's because the package is not designed to be used with vertical rules...

Answer (score 1):

Use this simpler code, which automates the insertion of bullets in the second column, and adds a 3rd column for the values `k/9`. Last: vertical rules should be avoided with booktabs, these ones aren't so nice, in my opinion. If you absolutely want them, I suggest thick grey rules, and `\cmidrules` replaces with  `addlinespace`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright, svgnames]{report}%{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\input{config.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\defaultaddspace}{1.5ex}
    \begin{tabular}{r!{\color{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\vrule width 4pt}>{$\bullet$~}l@{~}r}
    \toprule
    Élément évalué & Commentaire \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{Utilisabilité de l'osselet} &   Taille et poids adéquats & (9/9)\\
     & Facile à utiliser & (4/9) \\
     & Texture adaptée à la saisie & (9/9)\\
     & Position des capteurs adaptée & (8/9)\\
    \addlinespace
    \multirow{4}{*}{Utilisabilité du cube} &  Taille et poids adéquats & (9/9)\\
     &  Facile à utiliser & (6/9) \\
     &  Texture adaptée à la saisie & (9/9)\\
     & Position des capteurs adaptée & (9/9)\\
    \addlinespace
    \multirow{3}{*}{Utilisabilité du bracelet} &  Taille et poids adéquats & (9/9)\\
     &  Facile à utiliser & (9/9) \\
 & Oubli au poignet & (3/9)\\
\addlinespace
\multirow{5}{*}{Utilisabilité du verre} &  Taille et poids adéquats & (8/9)\\
 &  Facile à utiliser & (8/9) \\
 &  Texture adaptée à la saisie & (8/9)\\
 &  Position des capteurs adaptée & (9/9)\\
 & Bord trop épais & (5/9)\\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{Potentiels problèmes} &   Risque de chute et de casse pour le verre 
    & (3/9) \\
         &  Contact possible électronique/eau pour le verre & (1/9)\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Résumé des résultats d'utilisabilité de l'étude d'utilisabilité et d'acceptabilité avec des patients}
        \label{recap_utilisabilite}
        \end{sidewaystable}

    \end{document}
```

[image]